# Best way to represent a mobile attachment button and interaction?

Tags: mobile, ios, material-design

I'm new as a UX mobile designer and I have some trouble to represent an *Add Attachment* button to a form? How should I do that? I can't find any good examples.

Firstly, I designed a classic button inside my form but I don't know if this is the correct way... I also checked the material design chart from google but there is no example either.

[image: Screenshot of Add Attachment button]

Comment: could you provide a mock-up?

Comment: Sure, it's done!

Comment: I don't see a problem with what you have.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't necessarily a "correct" way.

1. The user needs to understand what he needs to do.
2. The CTA must be in a place that is easily seen and follows the user's train of thought as he's completing the form. Therefore the CTA can be anyplace in the form.
3. The label (and icon if included) must be informative.

Often times companies ask for attachments at the end of the form but that isn't "necessary", it's convention.

The best answer is to ask your users. A/B test your designs. Show variations to as many appropriate people as possible: receptionists in your office and others, people in the coffee shop. The creation of mock-ups is fast and easy and the time and cost for asking is a minimal.

Feedback: 
I for one find the folder less intuitive than an icon of a file. (But that's me.)

Comment: +1 for the less intuitive folder, a file icon _would_ seem to be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the whole form, maybe a [raised button](https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html#buttons-raised-buttons) (which only contains text) would be useful in your case:

> Raised buttons stand out more than flat buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a raised button at the bottom of the form. It will be easy to see and will attract the viewer's attention.

[image]

In terms of the icon, use either an attachment icon or a file upload icon, both of which are shown below.

[image] [image]

You could also use a normal flat button but that will be less eye-catching so decide by yourself which style you prefer to use.